# Hibernate good practice when detaching Objects

Tags: hibernate, coding-style, persistence

After I construct a hibernate query, my code goes as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<SendCommands> list = query.list();
session.evict( list );
if( list.isEmpty() ) 
   return null;
SendCommands dst = list.get( 0 );
return dst;
```

What is the "good" practice for this example:

1) detaching (evicting) the entire result set, then returning the first object of that set,  or

2) detaching (evicting) only the first object of the set:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<SendCommands> list = query.list();
if ( list.isEmpty() ) 
    return null;
SendCommands dst = list.get( 0 );
session.evict( dst );
return dst;
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Why do you need to detach objects?

Comment: I need to detach objects to pass them to another layer. according to documentation , the objects will be lost at the end of a transaction, why I want to detach them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to detach the objects. Hibernate entities are POJOs, and are not lost at the end of the transaction. When the session is closed, they become detached automatically. But you can still use then and access their data, unless the data is marked as lazy-loaded and has not been fetched while the entities were attached.

Comment: Thanks!  can you tell me what happens if it has a lazy-loading field, and the session is closed. Would this field become a null pointer? Or would Hibernate throw an exception?  

Also: if I don't detach an object, return it, and somewhere else (same session, different Thread) update it. would the returned value change?

Comment: You'll get an LazyInitializationException. Your second questio doesn't really make sense, because you shouldn't use the same session across different threads. A session is single-threaded. This basic, but very important stuff when using Hibernate. You should definitely reasd the hibernate reference documentation, where all this is described: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single